# Is it is possible to search my comment activity history?

Tags: support, comments, recent-activity

I was messing around with the settings of the GIMP earlier, and I found a potential answer to a question I remember commenting on a while ago - I have tried searching through the search box from my profile and generally, but can't seem to find it (it may have been deleted anyway) - so is there anyway I can search through my previous comments?

*N.B. Not by going through very slowly every single page of comments I have done on the site with the Find tool.... (1643 comments, 83 pages) - I don't think I'll bother then*

Comment: All the roads leads to [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Can you describe the question at all?

Comment: @Seth - It was about how to remove the GIMP logo or something, and I just found an option for that in the rc file whilst searching for something else - I mainly remember as there was a discussion about the name of the logo being Wilber or something (it is, the option is `(toolbox-wilber yes)`)

Comment: Oh that one? lol. Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: This is the one I remember: http://askubuntu.com/questions/413501/how-to-remove-gimp-logos-from-gimp-interface. Is that it?

Comment: @Seth - yes :D - I think i searched for 'wilber', but 'wilbur' in the comment (computers + search terms :(  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did eventually start SQLing as @Braiam suggested and used [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/206955/user-comment-string-search?commenttext=gimp):

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT [Id] AS [Comment Link] FROM comments WHERE userid = @UserId
and text like  '%##commenttext##%'
```

Works much better than the search box - didn't find ANYTHING though

---

**Edit:**
[Seth found it anyway](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/10483/is-it-is-possible-to-search-my-comment-activity-history#comment19521_10483) :D